Theorem 16.5, Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 142 Theorem 16.5 it states:
$$\int_{D}f\leq\int_{A}f$$
at the end of that page.
Here, $D=S_{1}\cup\cdots\cup S_{N}$ is compact since $S_{i}=Support\phi_{i}$ and $\{\phi_{i}\}$ is a partition of unity on $A$ having compact supports. Here, $f$ is non-negative. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection of all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$. We know that $\int_{A}f=\sup_{E\in\mathcal{D}}\{\int_{E}f\}$.
If $D\in\mathcal{D}$, we could easily get $\int_{D}f\leq\sup_{E\in\mathcal{D}}\{\int_{E}f\}=\int_{A}f$. However, we don't know whether the compact set $D=S_{1}\cup\cdots\cup S_{N}$ is rectifiable or not. So we cannot conclude $D\in\mathcal{D}$ and $\int_{D}f\leq\sup_{E\in\mathcal{D}}\{\int_{E}f\}=\int_{A}f$. (It is possible $D\notin\mathcal{D}$.)
How to fix this problem?
This a question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. I show you the whole context of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statement with the red line.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

First of all, by the proof of Lemma $15.1$ you get that there exists a compact, rectifiable set $E$ such that $D\subseteq E \subset A$. Then we use Lemma $16.4$ to get
$$ \int_A \phi_i f = \int_E \phi_i f. $$
With this we can replace $D$ by $E$ everywhere in the Munkres chain of inequalities and the ones you are worried about follows from Theorem $13.3$, respectively the definition of the extended integral as pointed out in Anne Bauval's answer.

You are right, my friend. I'm so appreciated. I will change the "silly" title of this question as you command (Whatever it is). But I still think Munkres' writing in this theorem may cause trouble for self-learners.  The title should warn readers in future, there is some gap here at least.

It should be modified as following:
$\int_{D}[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}f]\leq\int_{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}f]\leq\int_{E}f\leq\int_{A}f$. Am I right?

@studyhard You don't need to use $\int_D$ anywhere, you can directly go from $\int_A$ to $\int_D$.

@studyhard Yes, it there is a minor gap, but this is a normal thing. If you happen to read a research paper, you will with high probability encounter a gap, or a minor mistake. It is a key skill to spot those and come up with a fix. Also, if you disagree with somebody in mathematics, you might want to express this in a calmer fashion than you have displayed it before. People do not take it well if you become aggressive for no reason (a lesson I had to learn myself).

Thanks for this lesson. I will remember your words.

What do you mean "You don't need to use $\int_D$ anywhere (do you mean $\int_E$ here?), you can directly go from $\int_A$ to $\int_D$?" I cannot understand. I need to use $\int_E$ as I wrote above.

@studyhard I mean what I wrote. We have $$ \int_A \phi_i f = \int_E \phi_i f $$ as $\phi_i$ vanishes outside of $D$ (and hence in particular outside of $E$). Thus, we already start with $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \int_A \phi_i f = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_E \phi f. $$ I don't see why you think we need to use $\int_D$ anywhere.

I can understand your idea. You are right. But it seems also right that I keep using $\int_D$ as what Munkres wrote, and only modify the following: $\cdots=\int_{D}[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}f]\leq\int_{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}f]\leq\int_{E}f\leq\int_{A}f$. Only change the last few lines of "We conclude that..." Am I right?

I see not benefit in not changing right away, but whatever floats your boat.

OK, I will use your method when I write my notes. Thanks for your help. I will remember your words.

I still think that in your title, you should replace "A big mistake in" with something like "Help me understand".
$$\int_Df\le\sup_{E\in\mathcal{D}}\{\int_{E}f\}$$
because $f\ge0$ and $\exists E\in\mathcal D,\;D\subseteq E.$
